# Passenger error #2 Cannot stat config.ru

Tags: apache, hosting

Please help me when I accessing my website its showing error related to file permission.

```
An error occurred while trying to access
 '/home/jhoney/public_html/config.ru': Cannot stat
 '/home/jhoney/public_html/config.ru': Permission denied (errno=13)

 Apache doesn't have read permissions to that file. Please fix the
 relevant file permissions.
```

But this file is not exist when I trying to give permission.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Comment: Sorry it added by mistake please help.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the permissions for the folder, in your case public_html to 755